# Best way to return list of entities in many-to-many situation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

*I don't really know how to correctly name this question so feel free to edit.*

I have really simple database model that has many-to-many relations between `User` and `UserGroup`. Now it works just fine but the way I return list of groups he is attached is not too pretty. I think there is some better way to do that with LINQ tweaking or something similar.

This is what I have so far, again - it works, but I think this is possible with one query.

```
public virtual List<UserGroup> UserGroups
{
    get
    {
        var _db = new MainDataContext();
        var userGroupUsers = _db.UserGroupUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == Id);
        var userGroups = new List<UserGroup>();
        userGroupUsers.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            userGroups.Add(x.UserGroup);
        });

        return userGroups;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

```
return _db.UserGroupUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == Id)
                         .Select(t => t.UserGroup)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works better.